# discrete sum of Gaussian functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there a special closed form (with general theta or other functions) for
the sum 
 $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(2 \pi n +z)^{2}/(2 \sigma^{2})}$?

Comment: Expanding the square you get $e^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}\theta(.,.)$, also your function is $2\pi$ periodic, writing its Fourier series you'll have the functional equation of the theta function. The special values of $\theta(z,\tau)$ are at $z\in \Bbb{Q}$, $\tau = \Bbb{Q}+\Bbb{Q} i\sqrt{d}$ with $d$ a squarefree integer (this is the theory of elliptic curves with complex multiplication)

Comment: Plus the zeros given by the Jacobi triple product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third Jacobi theta function
$$\theta_3(x,q) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2} e^{2nix}$$
so (expanding out the square) your function is
$$e^{-z^2/(2\sigma^2)} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-2 \pi^2 n^2/\sigma^2} e^{-2\pi n z/\sigma^2} = e^{-z^2/(2\sigma^2)} \theta_3(iz/\sigma^2, e^{-2\pi^2/\sigma^2})$$